# NoRouteToHostException "Address not available"

Tags: android, http, exception, android-volley

In my Android app, I do poll a device (Wallbox) every 5 seconds using the Volley library. For one customer, I get

> java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Address not available

after several hours. Usually, using the exactly same type of device and at my place, this polling works for days, but not at (at least) this customer.

The device address is on the local LAN.

I have not found any description about "address not available" that might apply to my case, or at least I did not see the point.

The call is always the same:

```
http://192.168.160.152/api/status
```

As this is live data, I set ".setShouldCache(false)" for the request.

Meanwhile, other HTTP requests (in this case, a query to a WWW address, also polled continuously), even using Volley, continue to work:

```
https://backend.powerfox.energy/api/2.0/my/***********/current
```

The connection works again after rebooting the device (and at the same original IP address), so I guess it has nothing to do with the wallbox or the router.

And if the wallbox would be not available, I assue I would get "unreachable"  error or such.

Is there someone who can help me, what could cause **that** exception ("**address not available**"), and what can I do about it?

Comment: Presumably, the "wallbox" falls off the network from time to time.

Comment: A related possibility is that the network router flips the IP address assignment of the wallbox from time to time, so while the wallbox is on the network, it is not at the IP address where you are looking for it.

Comment: Sorry, I must add, the connection works again after rebooting the device (and at the same original IP address), so I guess it has nothing to do with the wallbox or the router. 

And if the wallbox would be not available, I assue I would get "unreachable" error or such. The "Address not available" is a strange error... (I just edited my question with these facts, thanks for remembering)

Comment: Does the device have a SIM card? If so, is the device perhaps falling off of the WiFi network for some reason (e.g., issues with the router)? That would explain the ability to access your Web service while not being able to reach the wallbox.

Comment: No, sorry. It is still reachable via a WebSocket protocol (by the app from the manufacturer), just the HTTP access stops working. And while it starts to work for several hours again after rebooting the smartphone, it must be a problem at the Android side...